# Significance of requiring a nowhere vanishing derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

The following is from J.S. Milne's notes on modular forms.  He gives a definition of compatible coordinate neighborhoods.

[image]

What is the significance of requiring that the derivative be nowhere vanishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No significance.

If you assume only that they are holomorphic, interchanging the role of $i, j$ gives

$$z_j \circ z_i^{-1} :z_i (U_i\cap U_j) \to z_j(U_i\cap U_j)$$

is holomorphic. But this is the inverse of $z_i \circ z_j^{-1}$. Thus both of them has non-vanishing derivatives, which can be checked using chain rule.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Was afraid I was missing something, thank you.

Comment: @D_S The significance is that the derivative of an injective holomorphic map (and of a biholomorphic map) is nowhere vanishing. If you assume the map is biholomorphic, you assume its derivative is nowhere vanishing.